# how do I bind database values to Spinner dropdownlist in android code?

Tags: android, mysql

I have used following simple code to fetch values from mysql database table.

> I don't know how to bind these values to Spinner dropdown list

```
 public String select() throws JSONException
{

            //ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));

            try
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydemo.com/select.php");
                //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }
            catch(Exception e)
        {

        }     

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();

        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                }     


                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                return (json_data.getString("name"));



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Copy the data from the `JSONObject` into POJOs that you wrap in an `ArrayList`, then use `ArrayAdapter`, or
- Use a better JSON parser (e.g., Google's [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) that can generate your `ArrayList` for you, then use `ArrayAdapter`, or
- Replace all your code above with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (and GSON) to retrieve and generate your `ArrayList` for you, then use `ArrayAdapter`, or
- Create your own subclass of `BaseAdapter` that you use to wrap your `JSONObject`, along the lines of how `ArrayAdapter` adapts arrays and `CursorAdapter` adapts `Cursors`

And there are other possibilities as well, though those should get you started.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Retrofit) demonstrates the Retrofit+GSON approach, pulling data from the Stack Exchange API and putting it in a `ListView`. Using a `Spinner` is just a matter of reconfiguring the `ArrayAdapter` and using appropriate layouts.